# How come when I call this function my table isn't generating?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm trying to generate a table with 2 rows, with 4 cells each. Each cell is supposed to contain an image. What am I doing wrong? When I call my function, nothing happens.

```
function generateTable()
{

    var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    table.setAttribute("id", "gameBoard");

    var row1 = document.createElement("TR");
    row1.setAttribute("id", "r1");

    table.appendChild(row1);

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var card = document.createElement("TD");
        var card_img = document.createElement('img');
        card_img.setAttribute("img", "images/card_back.png");
        card.appendChild(card_img);

        row1.appendChild(card);
    }

    var row2 = document.createElement("TR");
    row2.setAttribute("id", "r2");

    table.appendChild(row2);


    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        var card = document.createElement("TD");
        var card_img = document.createElement('img');
        card_img.setAttribute("img", "images/card_back.png");
        card.appendChild(card_img);

        row2.appendChild(card);
    }
```

}

Comment: You don't actually place the table onto the page at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end you must do `document.appendChild(table);`, as you are not adding the element to the page (which you might think you do with `document.createElement`, but that does not add anything to the DOM).

If you want to add it to a specific element, then I would modify your function to accept a parameter for the id of the div that shall contain your gameboard.

```
generateTable(elementId) { ... }
```

and at the end:

```
let toAdd = document.getElementById(elementId);
toAdd.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the line "document.appendChild(table); after the last for loop and I get the following error: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed."

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it by doing document.body.appendChild(table);